# Laravel MongoDB Jenssegers How to get "_id" of a document

Tags: mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I'm trying to get a list of users in **MongoDB**. The `_id` is empty, so I can't process it properly.
How can I get the `_id` of a document using **MongoDB** for **Laravel**?

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "per_page": 15,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": null,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 1,
    "data": [{
        "_id": {},
        "name": "Firstname Lastname",
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2y$10$fmTpx5k0FdWC5HEqUcBtKe2nwZzt2nwSZ6oht8d3ytsuh5l7Kh8O2",
        "updated_at": {},
        "created_at": {},
        "remember_token": "k7FQe0xbE5GJ6qPL9QK9CsHQrmBOKQkBO0zyKzkKibvRwnVL2tDXBBvK8zFW"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code where you're trying to get a list of users?

Comment: I fount the solution, in blade you just have to use $user ["_id"] to get the _id, I was using $user->{'_id'}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case somebody needs it, the data is returned by array.
you can do a var_dump in blade using {{ var_dump ($user) }} and then you see the correct way to get the data is

{{ $user ["_id"] }}